# async/await keyword with forEach loop - typescript

Tags: typescript

My code is working well before I add forEach loop & aync keyword:

```
  const peopleIds= ["John-01-01A", "Doe-01-01B", "Lily-01-01C"];
  const suggestedPeople: KnownPeople[] = [];

    const personInfo = await getPersonInfo(personIds[0]);
    const PersonModel: IPersonInfo = {
      id: personInfo.id,
      info: personInfo,
    };
    suggestedPeople.push(PersonModel as KnownPeople);

  return suggestedPeople;
```

However, after I wrap it with a forEach loop and async keyword, it doesn't work any more:

```
  const peopleIds= ["John-01-01A", "Doe-01-01B", "Lily-01-01C"];
  const suggestedPeople: KnownPeople[] = [];

  peopleIds.forEach(async personId => {
    const personInfo = await getPersonInfo(personId);
    const PersonModel: IPersonInfo = {
      id: personInfo.id,
      info: personInfo,
    };
    suggestedPeople.push(PersonModel as KnownPeople);
  });
  return suggestedPeople;
```

Do you have any idea what possibly caused it?

Comment: use `for of` loop instead of `forEach(...)`. `forEach()` doesn't works well with the `async-await` syntax.